# using a delegate to return an object not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view controller that has an action to present a view cotroller

GoodNewsBodyViewController.h

```
@interface GoodNewsBodyViewController : UIViewController<EventListDelegate>
```

GoodNewsBodyViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)goToEvents:(id)sender {
                EventTableViewController* eventsController = [[EventTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventTableViewController" bundle:nil];

        [eventsController setListOfEvents:goodNews.Events];
        //try both ways
        [eventsController setDelegate:self];
        eventsController.delegate = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:eventsController animated:YES];
    }
    - (void)loginFormDidFinish:(EventTableViewController*)loginForm {
        // do whatever, then
        // hide the modal view


        EventViewController *eventController = [[EventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventViewController" bundle:nil];
        [eventController setEvent:loginForm.event];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventController animated:YES];
        // clean up
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

EventTableViewController.h

```
@class EventTableViewController;

@protocol EventListDelegate
- (void)loginFormDidFinish:(EventTableViewController*)loginForm;
@end
@interface EventTableViewController : UIViewController <RKObjectLoaderDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    id<EventListDelegate> delegate;
    NSArray* eventList;
    Organisation* organisation; 
    IBOutlet UITableView* _tableView; 
    NSMutableArray* listOfEvents;
    Event* event;

}
@property (strong) id<EventListDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView* _tableView; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* eventList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Organisation* organisation; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* listOfEvents;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Event* event;
```

When an event is selected in the eventstableviewcontroller i want that event to be posted back. Im trying to do it by having the event as a property that gets set in the didselect method of the eventstableviewcontroller. The events list is being presented and when an event is selected it, the list disapears. This is all correct but the 
- (void)loginFormDidFinish:(EventTableViewController*)loginForm;

event doesnt seem to fire, I have got break points set there but they never get hit... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Delegate callbacks aren't really "events".  You've shown your implementation of `loginFormDidFinish:`, but where's the code that actually calls it?

Comment: its in the EventTableViewController.h, reading the objective c documentation this is how to declare delegates

Comment: Yes, you *declared* it correctly in the header.  But declaring it is only half the battle.  You still have to *call* the delegate method from somewhere in your actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `loginFormDidFinish:` method should be like this

-

```
(void)loginFormDidFinish:(EventTableViewController*)loginForm {
        // hide the modal view
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];//without animation


        EventViewController *eventController = [[EventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventViewController" bundle:nil];
        [eventController setEvent:loginForm.event];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventController animated:YES];
        [eventController release];
        // clean up
}
```

Comment: nope, method still doesnt get hit. Im am using arc so theres no 'release'